# Starting windows apps from cmd using path executables

Tags: cmd, windows-10

I have an app that listens to certain process events, such as starting a program and than recording the full commands. I would like to replay starting the programs using the commands as well. For some programs e.g. word, this works very well.

For windows app programs, this does not work. For example, starting calculator:

```
Command inputs: "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1709.2703.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Calculator.exe"

Access is denied.
```

I could start the calculator using `calc`, but unfortunately, I don't have that information in my program. Is there any way to start such a program using the executable path?

I used admin mode for the latter command.

Comment: open cmd with administrator permissions

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running cmd as administrator?

Just kidding ;-)

Actually, starting Windows Store apps (or UWP apps, or whatever they are called these days) is not easy. Finding the correct command line for them is a very long-winded process. It's described here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/starting-windows-10-store-app-from-the-command/836354c5-b5af-4d6c-b414-80e40ed14675?auth=1

I know it's bad form to just give links as answers, but on this occasion the answer itself would take pages to write. If the above link disappears, google "Starting Windows Store apps from the command line".

Comment: I guess there is no easier way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

I think cmd running as a normal user it required administrator access, **try cms as administrator.**